# Insert a new column with duplicated index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to insert new column by preserving index and eventually adding missing index from the new Dataframe. Starting data frame looks:

|  | M1 | RAW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS |  |  |
| 999 | 3.65 | A |
| 999 | 3.58 | B |
| 999 | 3.50 | C |

and I would like to add a new column and get back a new dataframe like:

|  | M1 | M2 | RAW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BS |  |  |  |
| 999 | 3.65 | 3.35 | A |
| 999 | 3.58 | 3.38 | B |
| 999 | 3.50 | 3.30 | C |

So I'm using something like:

```py
value = {'M1': [3.65, 3.58, 3.5], 'BS': [999, 999, 999], 'RAW':['A', 'B', 'C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(value).set_index('BS')
value = {'M2': [3.35, 3.38, 3.3], 'BS': [999, 999, 999]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(value).set_index('BS')
df = df.join(df1, on='BS', how='outer')
```

with the result of:

|  | M1 | M2 | RAW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BS |  |  |  |
| 999 | 3.65 | 3.35 | A |
| 999 | 3.65 | 3.38 | B |
| 999 | 3.65 | 3.30 | C |
| 999 | 3.58 | 3.35 | A |
| 999 | 3.58 | 3.38 | B |
| 999 | 3.58 | 3.30 | C |
| 999 | 3.50 | 3.35 | A |
| 999 | 3.50 | 3.38 | B |
| 999 | 3.50 | 3.30 | C |

Which is indeed wrong. I would like to preserve index (BS column) and eventually add newly index when inserting a new column.

Comment: How do you want to merge?  why would `3.65` be associated with `3.35` and not any other number?what is the logic behind the association?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.concat` instead of `merge`:

```
pd.concat([df, df1],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       M1 RAW    M2
BS                 
999  3.65   A  3.35
999  3.58   B  3.38
999  3.50   C  3.30
```

Comment: Because your index for `df2` is different. What would your expected output look like for different index in this example?

Comment: if you add a new column like:


   value = {'M3': [3.35, 3.38, 3.3], 'BS': [998, 999, 999]}
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(value).set_index('BS')
   pd.concat([df, df1, df2], axis=1)

Doesn't work because the first BS=998 won't let it concat

Comment: Row BS=998 M3=3.35 RAW=Nan at beginning and the rest at end or within the BS=999

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Are you adding a new row? which of the 3 existing rows will get the two BS=999 entries?

Comment: Mmmhhh! You are right! Let me better check what I want from my merged dataframe

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be confusing as to how you can associate the values. Assuming we claim that the values are associated in the order they appear, then we could use that notion/logic to join the datasets:

```
(df.reset_index().set_index('BS', append = True)
   .join(df1.reset_index().set_index('BS', append = True))
   .reset_index(level = 0, drop = True))

       M1 RAW    M2
BS                 
999  3.65   A  3.35
999  3.58   B  3.38
999  3.50   C  3.30
```

Comment: Yes! Assumption was confusing, I've realized that the index was not right regarding my use case. So I'm closing this question